# SQL injection protection in java

Tags: java, html, sql

As you may have seen from my posts I have been working on securing php webpages against vulnerabilities.

With the help of the community I have come on leaps and bounds, so thank you all.

I have now been faced with my first Java app, and am looking for some help to prevent sql injection on the below code, can any provide help and guidance.

```
 <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

 <%
 String username="";
 String password="";
 Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
 if (cookies != null)
 for (Cookie c : cookies) {
    if ("username".equals(c.getName())) {
     username= c.getValue();
    }
    else if("password".equals(c.getName()))
    {
        password= c.getValue();
    }
   }

  %>
 <form action="LoginValidator" method="post">
 <table> 
<tr><td>UserName: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="<%=username%>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password :</td><td><input type="text" name="password" value="<%=password%>"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Remember me: </td><td><input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" checked/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td class="fail"><% if(request.getParameter("err")!=null){out.print(request.getParameter("err"));} %></td></tr>
```

Thanks everyone

The page being used to login is login.jsp but it seems the sql call is coming from another page, as the code below shows:

```
<%
if(session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn")!=null)
{
Connection con=new   DBConnect().connect(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-  INF/config.properties"));

String id=request.getParameter("id");
if(id!=null && !id.equals(""))
{
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs =null;
         rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from users where id="+id);
          if(rs != null && rs.next())
          {
            out.print("UserName : "+rs.getString("username")+"<br>"); 
            out.print("Email : "+rs.getString("email")+"<br>"); 
            out.print("About : "+rs.getString("about")+"<br>"); 

            //Getting Card Details:
            ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select * from cards where id="+id);
             if(rs1 != null && rs1.next())
            {
               out.print("<br/>-------------------<br/>Card Details:<br/>-------------------<br/>");
               out.print("Card Number: "+rs1.getString("cardno")+"<br/>");
               out.print("CVV: "+rs1.getString("cvv")+"<br/>");
               out.print("Expiry Date: "+rs1.getString("expirydate")+"<br/>");
            }
             else
             {
                 out.print("<br/>No Card Details Found: <a href='changeCardDetails.jsp'>Add Card</a><br/>");
             }
          }
    }
     else
    {
    out.print("ID Parameter is Missing");
    }

    out.print("<br/><ul type='square'>");
    out.print("<li><a href='"+path+"/tasks/Messages.jsp'>Messages </a></li>"); 
     out.print("<li><a href='"+path+"/tasks/SendMessage.jsp'>Send Message </a></li>"); 
     out.print("</ul><br/>");
out.print("<br/><a href='"+path+"/tasks/forum.jsp'>Return to Forum &gt;&gt;</a>");     

 }
 else
 {
out.print("Please login to see Your Profile");
 }

 %>
```

Or Perhaps the call is coming from the login validator class as shown below:

```
{
                               ResultSet rs=null;
                               Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
                               rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from users where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");
                               if(rs != null && rs.next()){
                               HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                               session.setAttribute("isLoggedIn", "1");
                               session.setAttribute("userid", rs.getString("id"));
                               session.setAttribute("user", rs.getString("username"));
                               session.setAttribute("avatar", rs.getString("avatar"));
                               Cookie privilege=new Cookie("privilege","user");
                               response.addCookie(privilege);
                               if(request.getParameter("RememberMe")!=null)
                               {
                                   Cookie username=new Cookie("username",user);
                                   Cookie password=new Cookie("password",pass);
                                   response.addCookie(username);
                                    response.addCookie(password);
                               }
                               response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("ForwardMe?location=/index.jsp"));
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                      response.sendRedirect("ForwardMe?location=/login.jsp&err=Invalid Username or Password");
                               }

                           }
```

Comment: So where is the sql code?

Comment: In order to have a SQL injection vulnerability, the code needs to actually interact with a SQL database.

Comment: Sql injection can be prevented by filtering the variables received by the sql script, or preparing statements in case of php. I don't see anything like that here. You only show the sending of the data. Please post the code used to receive the variables and query the db

Comment: I think this is the vulnerable statement, Can any one advise how I can escape special characters from the below:

 rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from users where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");

I have been using real_escape_string for php, is there a similar for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the code for the `LoginValidator`. In general, the login assumes the username and password are already stored in an SQL database (or more often an LDAP database) and you are only doing a comparison. In that case, you are not subject to an SQL injection attack, since you are not storing anything in the database. If it is a registration process, where you will insert the username or password (best practice is to store the hash of the password, not the password itself), then in your `LoginValidator` code, parse the username and password for special characters that can be used in a SQL injection attack, such as `;,` etc. See the [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The only injection possibility here is in your 'id' variable.
You use statements which is good but you execute the query without preparing it first. Look at 'prepareStatement' to bind 'id' to your query so it is 100% safe